# name safe on top of type safe

Tags: xquery, eclipse-jdt, type-safety

Has anyone got the same need I have for a "name safe"--please define--on top of a "type safe"--please define?  I don't have any questions about type safes; I'm just looking for a name safe.

Sample question: you've built an xpath/xquery to run against xml.  Is there a way/tool that will check the "xml element/attribute name" against the schema during design and/or compile time?  This kind of need will not pop up if you map the XMl to a POJO.  I'm looking for something akin to an eclipse plugin that would do this by using [content assist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_assist) and real-time java analysis.

Actually, I'm hoping to find a tool like this to parse some JSON document, rather than XML.  I think that the XML community may have the most mature tools stemming from XQuery, and I'm most likely to discover this through that tag.

Comment: Could you please add definitions where I put "please define"?  You don't need to change the grammar surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

An XML Schema validator will check that an XML document conforms to a set of rules; I believe there are XSD (XML Schema Document) tools available for eclipse.

For JSON there's a thing called JSON Schema, although I think it is not as mature.